# TypeScript set a type or interface to be any member of an enum

Tags: typescript, types, enums, interface

I wanted to know what was the best way to set a type value to any member of an enum.

example

```html
enum daysOfWeekEnum{
    mon = 'Monday',
    tue = 'Tuesday',
    wed = 'Wednesday', 
    thu = 'Thursday',
    fri = 'Friday',
    sat = 'Saturday',
    sun = 'Sunday'
}
//any day of week
type dayOfWeek = daysOfWeekEnum

//effective assign the values in this way
type day = 'Monday' | 'Tuesday' | 'Wednesday'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enum is a type itself that can represent any value out of the set of declared values.

```
enum daysOfWeekEnum {
    mon = 'Monday',
    tue = 'Tuesday',
    wed = 'Wednesday', 
    thu = 'Thursday',
    fri = 'Friday',
    sat = 'Saturday',
    sun = 'Sunday'
}

let day: daysOfWeekEnum = daysOfWeekEnum.mon;

function log(value: daysOfWeekEnum) {
    console.log(value);
}

log(day); // ok -- prints "Monday"
log("Monday"); // ok -- prints "Monday"
log("asdfa"); // not ok - typescript error, "asdfa" is not a daysOfWeekEnum value
```

Comment: Hi thanks I meant more like ` type day = 'Monday' | 'Tuesday' |  'Wednesday' ...` etc , is there a way to iteratively add the types of an enum as a type annotation

Comment: `type day = 'Monday' | 'Tuesday' ...` is a valid type. They are known as union types. So you repeated the pattern for each day, then that is effectively the same as an enum, as far as typing goes. (`enum` emits actual JS objects so they have a runtime representation, whereas `type` is purely compiler time)